# Exponential distribution with less variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, terminology

The exponential distribution is nice - but no guarantee that event will ever happen - is there a distribution that has less variance than the exponential but also still *approaches* a memoryless-type-situation?

Comment: What do you mean "no guarantee that event will ever happen"? Probability of exponential distribution having finite value is $1$.

Comment: @mihaildI no, I don't think the PDF for the exponential ever reaches a Y value of 0. so there is some probability, however infinitesimal, that the event will never happen.

Comment: There is no such thing as "infinitesimal probability of event". Probability of an event is either zero, or some specific positive number.

Comment: No, the probability that the event happens is 0.99999999999999 repeating forever.

Comment: And this is exactly the same as probability $1$.

Comment: No it's not, my son of God, it is possible, however small, that it will never happen, because it never quite reaches 1

Comment: It's not possible (probability is eactly $0$). Number $0.999\ldots$ is exactly the same as number $1$. Check definition or real numbers in any analysis textbook, for example Rudin "Principles of mathematical analysis".